# Could not find method ndkVersion() for arguments [25.1.8937393]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, migration

I am opening a dart/flutter, Android app that was shelved some years ago and slowly working through the deprecated items, which I believe I have fixed. However, when I try to run the app in either Android Studio or via VSCode extension I get the above error.

I have updated the android/app/build.gradle file to have:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
```

However, the error persists.
I would appreciate some help resolving this.

Sid

Answer (score 1):

One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version” error on Android studio.

https://medium.com/@brianmutinda49/how-to-fix-one-or-more-plugins-require-a-higher-android-ndk-version-error-on-android-studio-4abaf3fcad00

Answer (score 0):

It mean some plugins require higher ndk version so change your ndk version to higher one. follow these steps.

Android studio.

```
Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Enable check box: NDK (Side by Side) > bottom right :Show Package Details > Select the NDK version(show in error) : in this case 25.1.8937393 > OK
```

Reload your android studio.

VS Code ( Configure specific versions of the NDK in your project) :

Go build.gradle

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    // Other configurations...
}
```

Reload code ediotor and configure it. If not work open your project on android studio and make changes like above. then reopen with vs code.